How to prove commutativity of two matrices with given condition below?
Hi Im reading some physics paper and there is following linear algebraic argument.
"Since A and B are Hermitian and Since $\mbox{Tr}(A^2 B)=\mbox{Tr}(B)=0$, A and B are commute."
But I can have any clue about this argument.
I think I have to use the properties of trace like
$\mbox{Tr}(A^2 B)=\mbox{Tr}(B A^2) \therefore \mbox{Tr}([A^2, B])=0$ 
or
$\mbox{Tr}(A^2 B)=\mbox{Tr}(ABA) \therefore \mbox{Tr}([A,[A, B]])=0$
but I'm lost my way.
Is there any point that I miss?

Look for counter-examples among 2x2 matrices. They probably have more properties than the ones you listed.

Ok I’ll read that paper more carefully
